# Registering multiple services to a single interface in WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: java, wso2, osgi, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to find a way to register multiple implementations to a single interface within the OSGI framework. Currently I have an implementation of the UserStoreManager interface which I register in the OSGI framework in the code below.

```
protected void activate(ComponentContext ctxt) {
    Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    CustomUserStoreManager customUserStoreManager = new CustomUserStoreManager();
    ctxt.getBundleContext().registerService(UserStoreManager.class.getName(), customUserStoreManager, props);
}
```

The problem is that there is already another implementation of the UserStoreManager interface which I can't remove.

How do I register my implementation in such a way that it won't cause issues with the other implementation?

I read about providing properties and how that can be used to solve this problem, however I do not believe that the properties I provide are being picked up by WSO2's Identity Server.

Both of the implementations of the UserStoreManager interface are used as secondary user stores within the identity server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to remove the existing UserStoreManager implementation. If you want to use your new customized UserStoreManager for the primary user store, replace the UserStoreManager class in the user-mgt.xml file and restart the server. Then this com.custom.user.manager.CustomCUserStoreManager will be used.

```
<UserStoreManager class="com.custom.user.manager.CustomUserStoreManager">
```

If you want to change it for secondary user store change the class name in the edit secondary user store in the management console.

Comment: I am trying to have both my UserStoreManager implementations working as a secondary user store at the same time. The issue I am running into is the fact that you seem to only be able to register a single implementation for a secondary user store in the OSGI framework.

Comment: You can register, another UserStoreManager implementations by adding one more ctxt.getBundleContext().registerService() method,

'protected void activate(ComponentContext ctxt) {
    .......
  ctxt.getBundleContext().registerService(UserStoreManager.class.getName(), customUserStoreManagerOne, props);
ctxt.getBundleContext().registerService(UserStoreManager.class.getName(), customUserStoreManagerTwo, props);
}'

Comment: The two user store manager implementations are separate projects. They both register themselves by calling ctxt.getBundleContext().registerService. However since they both have to call it using the same UserStoreManager interface they seem to overwrite each other, which causes a ClassNotFoundException to be thrown on one of them when we try to use it.

Comment: No, there will be no overwrite when registering the service. The ClassNotFoundException may because the bundle is not activated. You can start the server with -DosgiConsole and get the status of your bundle and make sure the service is registered. Find more info about OSGi debug here http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2014/01/how-to-debug-wso2-carbon-products-using.html

Comment: Both bundles get activated correctly. They also work separately from one another when the other one isn't present. When they are both active at the same time one of them will throw a ClassNotFound exception when it gets used.